# How to handle website addresses lacking http:// or https:// in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, http, wkwebview

My app needs to display websites from which some of the addresses lack the `http://` or `https://` prefix.  (The addresses come from a large database which I can't edit.)

I thought I'd simply check and add the prefix; `https://` seemed the best choice:

```
    if urlString.hasPrefix("http") == false
    {
        urlString = "https://" + urlString
    }

    if let url = URL(string: urlString)
    {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
```

But it turns out that some (older) websites don't load with `https://` as prefix, they need `http://`.

What should I do to make sure that all websites load?

Comment: You could prepend `http://` but of course you would also need to tweak your app to permit arbitrary loads, since otherwise `http` is illegal.

Comment: By the way, `urlString.hasPrefix("http") == false` is arguably wrong code. Use the not `!` operator to make a negative condition.

Comment: most sites will redirect http: -> https: if they support https, so that may be the safer way to go (though note Matt's comment above).  I'd say ! (not) vs == false is a personal style thing.  The `!` is more elegant, but also easy to miss when reading the code.